# Using cylindrical coordinates to find center of mass of solid of uniform density

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

Using cylindrical coordinates to find center of mass of solid of uniform density given by
$$x^2 + y^2 \le \frac{1}{4},\quad x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2 \le 1,\quad z \le 1.$$
I don't know how to set up the integrals. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your solid is the intersection of a cylynder and  a hemisphere. It is given by
$$S:=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\::\; 1-\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}\leq z\leq 1,\; x^2 + y^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}\right\}.$$
Moreover, by symmetry, the center of mass is along the $z$-axis.

Hence  you need to evaluate the $z$-coordinate only:
$$\bar z=\frac{\iiint_S z dxdydz}{\iiint_S  dxdydz}$$
Use the cylindrical coordinates.

Can you take it from here?